# Dynamic graph generation with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, gnuplot

I recently setup a cron on one of my servers to monitor the connection status. Basically a ping is issued every minute and the result is appended with the date to a data file.

I am currently able to fetch the data file trough apache and to generate a graph with gnuplot locally. But I wonder if there is an easy way to do this directly in apache.

I'd like to call some page in apache, which would trigger a gnuplot generation then render the generated file directly.

Do you know any tool/set of tools to help me do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this yourself. There are many monitoring applications available that already do what you want.

One solution just for the connection status could be Smokeping (it does much more, but is easy to configure for this purpose).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually don't really *want* to do this myself. But my searches were not conclusive. I'll try smokePing and keep you posted.